# pattern matching is not working for string in JAVA

Tags: java

I have an HTTP request input String decoded, which should be checked if it contains any operator like "[$,=?@#'<>.()%!]^".

I googled and found some working codes according to them, I have passed values with operators but it's not working :

```
String urlParameters = httpRequest.getQueryString();
try {
     String prevURL="";
     String decodeURL=urlParameters;  
     while(!prevURL.equals(decodeURL))  
     {
          prevURL=decodeURL;  
          decodeURL=URLDecoder.decode( decodeURL, "UTF-8" );  
      }
      urlParameters=decodeURL;
 }
  catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception on decoding:" + e);
}
Pattern pp = Pattern.compile("[$,=?@#'<>.()%!]^");
Matcher mm = pp.matcher(urlParameters);
if (mm.find()) {
    System.out.println("There is an Operator");
}
```

if the urlParameters has any of the operators mentioned above then, it should print "There is an Operator"

Comment: What do you mean by not working? Are you getting any error? or unexpected output? Can you share the results or errors you are getting?

Comment: if the urlParameters has any of the operators( [$,=?@#'<>.()%!]^ ) mentioned above then, it should print "There is an Operator"

Comment: I can read that! what is the problem? What is is the input and what is the output?

Comment: @SandeepKumar the problem is it is not detecting any operators from `urlParameters` eg : `urlParameters = "( water"<" ;` this should print `There is an Operator`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `^` operator at the end of the pattern - `"[$,=?@#'<>.()%!]^"`.

`^` - is used for matching position just before the first character of the string.

Remove `^` from your pattern and your logic should work

if `^` is needed as part of your special character set, include it inside `[]`

```
Pattern pp = Pattern.compile("[$,=?@#'^<>.()%!]");
```

Comment: If the minor correction you are pointing out really be the only problem, then you should just vote to close as a typo question.

Comment: @ashishkumar Thanks for the info and its working, but how to add `^` ?. @Tim it is not a typo I need `^` symbol also to be matched.

Comment: @ashishkumar `Pattern pp = Pattern.compile("[$,=?@#'^<>.()%!]");` this is working but will this affect by any means ?

Comment: No, it will not at all effect. With the pattern you have given, it will match these characters any where in the string. If you want to be specific that you only want to match at the start of the string, you could place the `^` at the start

Answer (score 0):

```
String urlParameters = httpRequest.getQueryString();
try {
     String prevURL="";
     String decodeURL=urlParameters;  
     while(!prevURL.equals(decodeURL))  
     {
          prevURL=decodeURL;  
          decodeURL=URLDecoder.decode( decodeURL, "UTF-8" );  
     }
     urlParameters=decodeURL;
 }
 catch (Exception e) {
     System.out.println("Exception on decoding:" + e);
}

 if (Patern.matches("^[$,=?@#'<>.()%!]",urlParameters)) {
      System.out.println("There is an Operator");
}
```